# Angular-ui-bootstrap - Date Picker - How can I restrict access to the date-selector in popup?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

At the moment, I can first select the year, then the month, and then, the date. However, I only need access to month and the year. I'm not sure how to disable the date-selector option.

Also, I would like to get rid of all the footer buttons (today, clear, etc) in the date-picker as well. How can I achieve this ?

I'm looking for something similar to '$scope.showweeks = false;'

Below is my Plunker example

[Plunker- Month year picker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jcG2uwUJlwgmJgD36y6J?p=preview)

Please feel free to direct me to any documentations available. So far, I could only find

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Thanks

Comment: Can you check these url :http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=2&minViewMode=1&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Comment: I don't think you can do that because datepicker supports only `show-weeks` attribute. I would write some directive that will add `ng-show` to relevant tag

Comment: @JQueryGuru - Thanks. It works well. But is there a way to access the same properties ( minViewMode: 1) using angular ?

Comment: @MaximShoustin - Is it possible to do it in a simpler way as in the bootstrap datepicker ? Would I be able to use the date-disabled (date, mode) function to disable the date selector? I tried playing around with it, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: There is a project for ui bootstrap that's a fork of the bootstrap-datepicker project: https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use datepicker for Bootstrap with jQuery wrapped by directive.

See <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JUSAaQoFtU8Kw1KyvXwN?p=preview)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.var1 = '07-2013';
});


app.directive('datetimez', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require : 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
          element.datetimepicker({
           format: "MM-yyyy",
           viewMode: "months", 
            minViewMode: "months",
              pickTime: false,
          }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
            scope.$apply();
          });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
   <div id="date" class="input-append" datetimez ng-model="var1">
      <input data-format="MM-yyyy" type="text" id="input1" name="input1"></input>
      <span class="add-on">
        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...!! I was just working on that after finding a similar post. It works well, except that I can't close it unless I click anywhere else on the screen. Is there an api for close button ? or may be double-click on a month to set it and close the pop-up ?

Comment: Which Browser do you use?

Comment: chrome at the moment, but need to support ie-9 if not 8.

Comment: you can grab sources from link `JQuery Guru` posted and add directive from my example. After, set option: `autoclose: true`. Hope it should work

Answer (score -1):

You can set mode in setting. 
For example for supporting only years, options would look like that:

```
    $scope.optionsYear = {
      showWeeks: false,
      minMode: 'year',
    };
```

And add options to datepicker:

```
data-datepicker-options="optionsYear"
```