# Datepicker angular directive for Bootstrap: Showing only months and years

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using `datepicker` from [Angular directives for bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I want to show only months and years in the datePicker pop-up, but could not find a way.

I tried the similar approach of [Bootstrap datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974394/bootstrap-datepicker-months-and-years-only) by giving it as `dateoptions`, but it did not work. Using `datepicker-mode="month" min-mode="month"` also did not helped.

Please find here [The link to plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cu29OkoGCj7HtklP5ayB?p=preview)

What we can observer is clicking on `month` in the datepicker, switch it to month view. So, this can be done, but how?

Comment: Changing the config to `datepicker-mode="'month'" min-mode="'month'"` worked, but still some issues are there. Check in the plunker. It only sets the initial mode, not the `min mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this topic.
They resolved your problem with directive and Jquery.
You could take a look.

[Angular-ui-bootstrap - Date Picker - How can I restrict access to the date-selector in popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323096/angular-ui-bootstrap-date-picker-how-can-i-restrict-access-to-the-date-selec)